# Asp.Net MVC3 Web grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

why this webgrid iterate every row in grid ??

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Domain.Model.BlogPost>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Posts";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}


@Html.ActionLink("Add Post", "Add", "Blog")

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
@foreach (var items in Model)
{
    <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: new[] {grid.Column("Title",header:""),
        grid.Column("",header:"",format:(item)=>Html.ActionLink("More Details","Details","Blog",new{postId=items.Id},null)),
        grid.Column("",header:"",format:(item)=>Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete","Blog",new{postId=items.Id},null)),
        grid.Column("",header:"",format:(item)=>Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Blog",new {postId=items.Id},null)), })

    </div>
}
```

my mean : for example for two data it renders 4 data , twice for every one !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `foreach` through the model. `GetHtml()` will do everything for you.

When you pass your `Model` into the `WebGrid()` constructor the grid now knows what data it has to render when you call `GetHtml()` so you don't need to do anything else.

This should do it:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);

    <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: new[] {grid.Column("Title",header:""),
        grid.Column("",header:"",format:(item)=>Html.ActionLink("More Details","Details","Blog",new{postId=item.Id},null)),
        grid.Column("",header:"",format:(item)=>Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete","Blog",new{postId=item.Id},null)),
        grid.Column("",header:"",format:(item)=>Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Blog",new {postId=item.Id},null)), })
     </div>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , so what is the 'items' in code above you have written? I have to use foreach because I get IEnumerable binded model and also need to model Id to Crud operation , as you can see in the code , details, delete and Edit

Comment: @EricNielsen just use `item`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, since I don't work with WebGrid much, but are you sure you need that `@foreach`?  Wouldn't `@grid.GetHtml()` return all the records?